# How to do kubernetes TCP health checks on a container?

Tags: kubernetes

I can't find the syntax on how to do it. How can I do TCP health checks on containers inside a pod?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with the tcpSocket definition:

```
livenessProbe:
  tcpSocket:
    port: 9000
  initialDelaySeconds: 120
  timeoutSeconds: 5
readinessProbe:
  tcpSocket:
    port: 9000
  initialDelaySeconds: 120
  timeoutSeconds: 5
```